# If $ f $is continuous on an open interval is the range,$ f((a,b))$, an open interval?

Tags: real-analysis

Given that $ f $ is a continuous real-valued function on $[a,b]$, then $f([a,b])$ is a closed interval. I am wondering if this fact follows for open intervals. Thanks

Comment: Consider constant functions.

Comment: A map which has the property that "the image of an open set is open" is called an "open map", and it is unrelated to continuity.

Comment: Will continuous maps always yield a closed interval?

Comment: On the interval $(-1,1)$, consider $y(x)=x$ and $z(x)=x^2$.

Comment: No, consider $f(x) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} x & x \le \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} &x \ge \frac{1}{2} \end{matrix} \right.$ for $x \in (0,1)$.

Comment: The continuous image of an open interval is an interval, but the image may be open,closed, or half-open.BTW,the set $\{0\}$ is equal to the closed interval $[0,0]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a closed (and bounded) interval $[a, b]$, then it is compact and connected. These are both properties which are respected by continuous functions in general, so $f([a, b])$ is compact and connected, and in $\Bbb R$, that means a closed interval.

For an open interval $(a, b)$, you can tell that $f((a, b))$ is connected, so it is an interval, but in general you cannot say what *kind* of interval (open, closed or half-open). Examples of all three:

- Open: $f(x) = x$ for any open interval $(a, b)$.
- Half-open: $f(x) = x^2$ for any open interval $(a, b)$ where $a<0<b$.
- Closed: $f(x) = \sin(x)$ for any open interval $(a, b)$ with $b-a > 2\pi$.

Comment: Why can't we tell what kind of interval $f((a,b))$ is?

Comment: @Javier Given a specific function, and a specific interval $(a, b)$ we can of course tell what $f((a, b))$ is. That's not what I mean. What I mean is that unlike $f([a, b])$, it can change depending on the function and interval. $f([a, b])$ is _always_ closed, while $f((a, b))$ can be anything.

Comment: The functions in your second and third example are not injective. What if $f$ is injective (hence strictly montone)?

Comment: @Filippo If $f$ is strictly monotone and continuous on $(a, b)$, then $f((a, b))$ will be the open interval $(f(a), f(b))$ (or $(f(b), f(a))$, if $f$ is decreasing).

Comment: @Arthur Makes sense, thank you! I guess this also works for $a=\infty$ or $b=\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

It does not, a simple counterexample is the function $f(x)=1$ with $I=(0,1)$. Here $f((0,1))=\{ 1\} $ which is not open in $\mathbb{R}$. Continuity means that the *inverse* image of open sets are open, hence, given any continuous function $f$ and open set $V$ in its codomain, $f^{-1}(V)$ must be open in its domain.

Answer (score 0):

With intermediate value theorem you can easily prove that if $f$ is continuous and *injective*, then the set $f((a,b))$ is indeed open.